# UITouch not return the correct position

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitouch

I have a problem...

I want to get the UITouch position in a sigle view below the main view.

My code is:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint previous = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:toolBarView];
    CGPoint current = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:toolBarView];
}
```

The problem is that it returns the position in any view instead of toolbarView.

What's the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U might want to correct

```
CGPoint current = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:toolBarView];
```

to:

```
CGPoint current = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[toolBarView view]];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it. User Interaction were not enabled for toolBarView.